# Error when w!riting a file "Can't delete backup file"

Tags: backup

I'm having a problem when writing to a file created by another user. When I try to do `:w` I get the error message `E506: Can't write to backup file (add ! to override)` and when I do `:w!` the file get's written but I still see this:

```
/share/home/file.txt" 161L, 9896C written
E207: Can't delete backup file
```

`:se backup?` returns `nobackup`. The privileges of thefile are `-rwxrwxrwx`

This happens in `neovim NVIM v0.5.0-445-gca02db1f9`. If I try it with an older nvim like `NVIM v0.2.2` it writes without any error just using `:w`.

**Edit:** more settings:

```
backupcopy=auto
backupdir=.,~/.local/share/nvim/backup
```

`set writebackup?` seems empty

Comment: `:h E207` and `:set writebackup?`

Comment: `:set writebackup?` returns `  writebackup` I'm not sure what that means the variable is set to; is it unset?

Comment: @moberg This means that Vim creates a backup file while writing the the file. This backup file is deleted after the write was successful (as you have `nobackup`). This is a security feature described in `:h E207`. It seems you don't have the necessary permissions to delete the backup file.

Comment: `set backupdir?`  returns `backupdir=.,~/.local/share/nvim/backup` Where can I find the backup file that you are referring to @Ralf?

Comment: @Moberg Would expect it beside the edited file or in `~/.local/.../backup`.

Comment: @Ralf I don't see it, I tried to figure out what name it would have. Do you know?

Comment: @Moberg I don't know. On Linux there is a tool named `strace` that might help to understand what Vim is doing exactly. Something like `strace -o trace nvim file`. After exit check the file `trace` and search for `unlink` (= delete file).

Comment: If anybody else has this issue, check /home/$USER/.local/share/nvim/swap where $USER is the user whose file you are editing. For whatever reason, swaps will occasionally cause this behavior. Most likely the program isnt properly sorting the current swap from older ones.